# Blender donut - geo node sprinkles not on top of icing

Tags: geometry-nodes

I am following the Blender 3.0 beginners tutorial on geometry nodes and i am following the tutorial exactly as is in the video only when he selects Reset children in the collection info node the sprinkles stick to the donut whilst my sprinkles sort of orbit around the donut.

[image]

Does anybody know whats wrong with it as i am completely lost at the moment

[Blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17QcGsK5wVhIaIOe7TwzlYNi_Apz-Be4f/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: looks like you didn't apply a scale maybe? if it doesn't help, please provide blend file

Comment: @Chris i applied all scales beforehand, here is the [blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17QcGsK5wVhIaIOe7TwzlYNi_Apz-Be4f/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the *Collection Information* Node you need to switch from *Original* to *Relative*.  You also need to enable *Reset Children*

Also, you must have created the sprinkles in edit mode.  Open the Sprinkles collection, select all of the sprinkles, right click and select *Set Origin to geometry*:

[image]

Comment: I tried it and the sprinkles just moved up a bit, it still looks the same as in the pic

Comment: @nikola ah, you needed to do three things.  see updated answer.

Comment: That did it! thank you so much :) why did it not work before?

Comment: You're welcome.  Maybe it didn't work before because you only tried one thing at a time, resetting between tries, but you had three problems?