# I've learning Blender through Blender's Guru's youtube tutorial... and have a problem

Tags: mesh

I've followed every single thing that he taught in the videos, but my sprinkles look like 2d on icing instead of 3d. Why do they look so flat? What should I do?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You need to change the collection information node from original to relative.  Does [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/250430/42221) answer your question?

Comment: Thank you for taking your time.. but no, it is still flat with relative I really appreaciate your answer though. They look 3D before I optted in Separate children and reset children in the collection info node, but once I placed them on the icing, they became flat.

Comment: Perhaps if you added your blend file to your question we could look at it and figure out a better answer. ([How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help))

Comment: I tried to use the blender file uploader, but it only allows to upload upto 30mb, so if you don't mind, can I share my google drive link here? https://drive.google.com/file/d/14YtPAFgMceVrA4Ju8_kjJCkS0iK2TOqR/view?usp=sharing

Again, thank you for taking your time for answering my question.

Comment: Hey! I just figured it out. I tried different options to make my sprinkle puffy, so hold the original sprinkles and press Ctrl+A > Scale(which I already did in earlier step), then all of sudden the puffiness came back! I don't know why the earlier Ctyl+A > Scale only applied the size of the sprinkles to icing not for puffiness. Anyway, thanks a lot for your time! :) I really appreciate it!

Comment: Cool. I am glad you figured it.